# Why are some of the badges are not in the badges section?

Tags: bug

I don't understand why are some of the badges not in the badge section (you cannot search for it) but you get awarded by it. For example, Good Question does not appear at the badge section but you still get awarded if 1k people read your post. Why so?

---

I am talking about the own user page here:

[image]

Comment: The "Good Question" badge is the 10th on the list of [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). It's unclear what you're asking. Please provide an example.

Comment: If that's the issue then this is a suitable dupe: [Why can't you see review-badges in your profile-page until you've earned them?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299809)

Comment: See also [Why aren't all the badges shown on the track menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263610/1099857)